# Appropriate model & context class separation (Architecture)

Tags: c#, web-services, design-patterns, architecture

I'm currently wondering what's the suggested way to separate plain model classes (for e.g. using them in Entity Framework, Web API, MVC, WCF...) from their application logic parts (server side tasks, threads etc.) utilizing the DRY principe.

Consider this pseduo example:

```
public class HorseOfDoom {

    private Thread _hungerThread;
    private Laser  _headMountedLaser = new Laser();

    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Health { get; set; }
    public int HungerLevel { get; set; }

    public HorseOfDoom() {
          _hungerThread.Start();
    }

    public void PewPew() {
        _headMountedLaser.PewPew();
    }

}
```

In this class we have both - model properties that describe the model (age, name,..), but also a thread and methods. I can use this class in Entity Framework, WCF and so on.. but what if I want to use the model in a ASP.NET MVC client application without exposing the methods, threads? Do I have to write the same class again? Do I need managers, adapters and facades? Could I use the buddy class pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Use a model fit for the context. DRY is not about repeating lines of code, it's about repeating behaviour. Your view model can have the same properties (copy paste ftw) as the business model, minus the methods. You can use Automapper to map one to the other. Chances are your view model will have more than only those properties, including validation attributes or other data neede by the view in a certain format.

A model to rule'm all is not good on the long term. Clean models will alow you to focus better on the context and avoid coupling to other contexts, which might use a very similar or identical model. Things change in time and it's easier to work with a specific model from the beginning even if that involves copy paste and it seems that you're repeating yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that a combination as you show it in your sample is not really desirable - **my main point** of critique would be the thread that already implies a very concrete way on how the object should behave. The probability is high that the thread contained in the class itself will make it harder to use the class in some environments. From my point of view, the platform that integrates the class should be able to choose how to orchestrate the actions of the class - of course the class can make some restrictions like "not to be used in a separate thread as the class is not implemented in a thread-safe way". 
As for the point of **whether to combine properties and methods** in a class: I don't think that there is a clear and always valid answer. It depends very much on how big the architecture of your application is and whether you are willing to pay the price for the separation in terms of complexity and overhead. 
The concept of combining properties and methods in a single class is usually referred to as **["Domain Model"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model)**. It is a very natural approach to design complex business logic. 
If you have an architecture that sets out to separate the layers very well, you'd have a Domain Model in the business logic that implements the business rules. These classes combine properties and methods, but these classes are mapped to simpler versions (e.g. DTOs) that only transport the data to other layers. This way, you also de-couple a service interface from the domain model and change them with minimal influences on the other layers. For instance, if you have complex classes in the domain model and you want to present only a part of this information in a web interface or through a service layer, you could create one or more DTO classes that contain exactly the data that is needed. Changes to the domain model will not necessarily affect clients so that you gain freedom in this respect.
**In a smaller architecture** however, you might not need to separate the layers with DTOs if you can live with the consequences. 
As for the mentioned example of **WCF**, you have separate service and data contracts that you typically implement in different classes. If you have additional methods in a class that serves as a data contract those methods will not be part of the data contract. You'd have to explicitly make the methods that you want to publish part of a service contract. If you don't share the classes with a service client (e.g. through a class library), the client will not even know that these methods exist.